# Partial derivative of absolute function

Tags: analysis

Midterms are coming up and I just have so many questions since I am now trying to prepare for it. I stumbled upon this question, how would I show a function is differentiable if its a 2 variable function with an absolute valued function in it, for instance:

Define: $$F:\Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R},$$

$$F(x,y) = x^2 |y|-y^2|x| +2x + 3y,$$

How can I show they are or arent differentiable at points $(1,1), (0,0), (0,1)$. The absolute value on the function really threw me off, as I am not familiar with partial derivatives with absolute valued function. It will be extremely helpful if I could see how to approach these kind of problems.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even without knowing the derivative of the absolute value, you can write what follows (I omit the linear term, which are obviously differentiable):

$$\begin{cases}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=2x|y|-\frac{d|x|}{dx}y^2,\\
\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=x^2\frac{d|y|}{dy}-2|x|y.\end{cases}$$

Now only two terms are problematic, namely $\frac{d|x|}{dx}y^2$ and $x^2\frac{d|y|}{dy}$. When $x=0$ or $y=0$, they vanish, and this answers for $(0,0)$.

At this point you can't escape telling more about the derivative of the absolute value. As this function is piecewise linear, its derivative is piecewise constant, and undefined at the angular point (argument $=0$).

Hence the above terms are safe at $(1,1)$, but unsafe at $(0,1)$.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I will try to read and understand this and ask questions if I fail to understand at certain points.

Answer (score 1):

There are two common definitions of the absolute value function that can be useful when doing calculus. The first is the piecewise definition:

$$|x| := \left\{ \begin{array}{2} x & x \geq 0 \\ -x & x>0 \end{array} \right.$$

Under this definition, you can break your function up into a piecewise function and analyze the behavior on each region ($x>0$ and $y>0$, $x>0$ and $y<0$, ...).

Another, less commonly known, definition is

$$|x| := \sqrt{x^2}.$$

You should convince yourself that these definitions are equivalent. This second definition can be nicer to work with, as

$$\frac{d}{dx} |x| = \frac{d}{dx} \sqrt{x^2} = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x^2}} 2x = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2}}= \frac{x}{|x|},$$
noticing that this gives the same result as the piecewise function, being $\pm 1$ for $x \neq 0$ and undefined if $x =0$.

Comment: Thank you very much for this clarification.

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, to prove or disprove that $F$ is differentiable on $a$, I would recommend using this definition of being differentiable.

$F$ is differentiable on $a=(a_x,a_y)$ if we can find a linear map $L_a:\mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ s.t. : $$F(a_x+x,a_y+y)-F(a_x,a_y)=L_a(x,y)+o(\|(x,y)\|).$$

For example for $(0,0)$ :

$$F(0+x,0+y)-F(0,0)=F(x,y)=x^2 |y|-y^2|x| +2x + 3y.$$

Let $L_{(0,0)}(x,y)=2x+3y$, we have :

$$F(x,y)=L_{(0,0)}(x,y)+x^2 |y|-y^2|x|.$$

Is $x^2 |y|-y^2|x|=o(\|(x,y)\|)$ ?

We chose $\|(x,y)\|=\|(x,y)\|_2.$
Note that this choice does not matter since we are in finite dimension and all norms are equivalent. It is just for convenience.

$$\left|\dfrac{x^2 |y|-y^2|x|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right|\leq\dfrac{x^2 |y|+y^2|x|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\leq\dfrac{(x^2+y^2)(|x|+|y|)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}(|x|+|y|) \underset{(x,y) \to 0}\to 0.$$

Then $F$ is differentiable on $(0,0)$.

Note that, for $(1,1)$ you can restrict yourself as a neighborhood of the point, since being differentiable on a point is a local concept, so you can get rid of the absolute values and then you can use the usual characterization with partial derivatives if you want. $(0,1)$ is a little more tricky then $(0,0)$ but the same reasoning should do it. And you can use the same idea to restrict yourself on a neighborhood of the point to get rid of the absolute value on $y$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try to read and understand this.

Comment: Ok so I read over the explanation, and according to how I learned differentiabilty of functions, we test it using: $$||F(x,y)-F(a) - T(x-a, y - a)||/||(x,y)-(a,a)||$$, so if i test it for (0,0) then I get the expression $$||x^2|y|-y^2|x|||/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$, but we are supposed to take the norm of the numerator, so what I dont get is how can we just compare the expression $$x^2|y|-y^2|x|$$ without taking the norm?

Comment: $\|x^2|y|-y^2|x|\|=|x^2|y|-y^2|x||$ since $x^2|y|-y^2|x|$ is a real quantity.

Comment: then technically from this point, we can just go: 

$$|x^2|y|−y^2|x||≤|x^2y|+|y^2x|≤x^2+y^2$$, then as what skyking has said, it becomes$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$ and this tends to 0 as $$(x,y)  \to 0$$, hence its differentiable at (0,0)?

Also if we take the partial derivative of F(x,y) with respect to x and with respect to y, then we have:
$$\partial F/\partial y = x^2y/|y|-2y|x|+3$$ and $$\partial F/ \partial x = 2x|y|-y^2x/|x|+2$$, however wont these partials be undefined for when its both (0,0) and (0,1) because of the expressions $$y/|y|$$ and $$x/|x| $$hence not being differentiable?

Comment: The partial derivatives exists at $(0,0)$. To prove it, you may use the definition of those quantities instead of doing that way. And yes, the function is differentiable at $(0,0)$. (So the partial derivatives must exist.)

Comment: ok Im quite unsure of how we can prove partial derivatives exist for when its (0,1) and (0,0) and (1,1). In particular how can I show that (0,1) partial doesn't exist? Im not very familiar with this quite yet, I would appreciate the help, thank you.

Comment: Both partials derivatives exist at $(0,1)$. But that is not enough to prove that the function is differentiable.

Comment: I will write my confusion more clearly in an answer form as comment section is too small.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67066/discussion-between-aurora-borealis-and-nicomezi).

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should try is to take the partial derivates. You see then that it's $C^1$ at $(1,1)$. As a consequence of this it's differentiable here.

For $(0,1)$ on the other side you even don't have partial derivates, so it cant be differentiable.

Finally at $(0,0)$ you do have partial derivates as if you fix one of the variable to zero the absolute terms vanish. You have $F'_x(0,0) = 2$ and $F'_y(0,0) = 3$. Now you would use the definition of differentiability to see if $2dx + 3dy$ would be a valid differential. So you estimate $|F(x,y)-2x-3y| = |x^2|y| - y^2 |x| | \le |x^2y| + |y^2x| \le x^2 + y^2$ if $x$ and $y$ is sufficiently small. This shows that $F$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Comment: I actually found that F is not differentiable at (1,1) despite all partial derivatives existing at (1,1) is that correct? So (0,0) it is differentiable, (1,1), (0,1) it is not differentiable.

Comment: @AuroraBorealis No, it's differentiable at $(1,1)$ since it has continuous partial derivates. At $(0,0)$ it's also differentiable (by check against the definition). However at $(0,1)$ it's not. I'll update the answer...

Answer (score 0):

There is still something I dont quite get about this for instance, reading on everything that has been posted, so here is the general way as I see from my book, to show differentiability, first:

1. They show partial derivatives exist at the point in question.
2. They show that it is differntiabl using:

$$\frac{||F(x,y)-F(a_x,a_y)-T(x-a_x,y-a_y)||}{|(x,y)-(a_x,a_y)||}$$, and as this expression tends to 0 as it tends to the point in question then its differntiable. So for our case with F(x,y), we have using :
$$\frac{||F(x,y)-F(a_x,a_y)-T(x-a_x,y-a_y)||}{|(x,y)-(a_x,a_y)||}=\frac{||x^2|y|-y^2|x|+2x+3y-F(0,0)-T(x,y)||}{||x+y||}$$, now T here is the Jacobian of F(x,y) at our first point (0,0). Here is my first question:

How can I properly show that F(x,y) has partial derivatives at points (x,y) say (0,0), (1,1) and (0,1) mentioned in the problem in my book. Because as long as I can show that these partials exist or dont exist, then its a matter of reducing the expression $$\frac{||F(x,y)-F(a_x,a_y)-T(x-a_x,y-a_y)||}{|(x,y)-(a_x,a_y)||}$$ then applying the limit and using squeeze theorem to show it tends to 0 hence its differntiable or doesnt hence not differntiable.

Can anyone please tell me how I can show this partial derivatives for $$F(x,y)$$ exist or does not exist at points $$(0,0) (1,0), (0,1)$$. My attempt is:

For point (0,0), then we can write $$F(x,y)$$ as firstly:

$$F(0,y) = 3y$$, then the partial of this is simply 3 with respect to y, 
$$F(x,0) = 2x$$, then the partial of this with respect to x, is 2, hence the partial exists at (0,0)? Similarly for (0,1), when we parital F(x,y) with leaving F(0,y) its F(x,y)= 3y, and Partial with respect to y is 3. Similary F(x,1) = |y|-y^2+2x+3, if we take the partial of this then we have:
$$\partial F(x,1)/\partial x = 2x-x/|x|+2$$ and $$\partial F(0,y)/\partial y = 3.$$

I am pretty sure this is not the way. Can anyone please help me with showing F(x,y) has partial derivatives for (0,0) and (1,1) and (0,1)?

Thank you.

Comment: The expected format is that the question contains the entire question including whatever approach you've tried to solve it (to include this is a good thing). The answers should be just that - answers. It's fine to edit your question to improve it - it's actually preferred (rather than try to complete it using comments and "answer"). Consequently this should better have been appended to your question as it's really not an answer.

Comment: @skyking thank you for the tips, and I finally managed to solve it.