# Proving Partial Derivatives Exist

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I thought I would write this to actually help me understand how to determine if a partial derivative exists at a certain point. For instance its related to the post that I have asked [Partial derivative of absolute function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2468751/partial-derivative-of-absolute-function/2468776?noredirect=1#comment5105003_2468776). So How would I know if a function F(x,y) is differentiable, for example in my post, I have the function, $$F(x,y) = x^2|y|-y^2|x|+2x+3y$$. For the point (0,0), and (1,1) and (0,0) how will I show that F(x,y) the partial derivatives exist at that point.

My thinking: do we just hold for instance the point (0,0), do we hold x fixed at 0 and y fixed at 0 then caculate the $$f_x ,f_y$$each respectively to the x and y we hold it fixed? Can I please get some guidance on this, I am very stuck at this trying to show a partial exists at a given point. Of course I could just use the definition of the partial derivative for instance:

Say $$F(x,y) = x^2|y|-y^2|x|+2x+3y,$$ then using the definition of partial derivative, we have:

$$\frac{\partial F(0,1)}{\partial x } = \displaystyle \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{F(h,1)-F(0,1)}{h}=\frac{h^2-|h|-3}{h},$$
But this is undefined for when tends to 0. Is this the way to find partial x and y for a given point? I would appreciate some thorough explanation on this, thank you.

Comment: On your last paragraph: $F$ turned into $f.$ Also, you need limit signs there.

Comment: @zhw ok very helpful indeed.